# Java Object Oriented Design

Tags: java

I'm just starting to learn and the books say that I can  use "pre-coded" classes and objects. How do I call these classes/objects in the beginning of my program? I understand basically what they are, and the idea that I can use these classes/objects in place of writing fresh code every time, but I cannot seem to figure out where I find these things and how I implement them.

Comment: What do you mean with *pre-coded* ?

Comment: Do you mean templates? Pretty much every Java IDE supports those. Classes are usually assigned a name which makes their intention clear.

Comment: He means class libraries. For example "String"

Comment: If you've written any Java code you already *have* used pre-coded classes. (Most likely, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

You certainly talk about the Java classes that come in JRE/JDK.
Those are used by including the jar in your classpath and provides the "default" java classes.
Like `String` in `java.util` package.

If you want to look at them, in the JDK you'll find the sources of these class.

Answer (score 0):

"Pre-coded", or pre-written Java classes, are pretty much the same concept as the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) - someone has written the code for you, was kind enough to document how you can use the code, and you may create instances (as necessary) through the prescribed way.

Say, for instance, I want an ArrayList holding Strings.  I would then code `ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>()`. You wouldn't have to go through the process of writing a dynamic self-expanding vector.

Comment: True, but it's also one of those classes that's hard to implement on your own, and is referenced a lot by beginners in the Java API.

Comment: Why not just use `String` then? It meets those criteria too.

Comment: @Tharwen Using `String` constructors is much worse as beginner advice.